# How to create a shell script (/bin/sh) with option -s and read input inside

Tags: shell, pipe, posix, sh

I want to run a shell script (POSIX) like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is a.sh
echo your age?
read age
echo "You are $age."
```

If this is thrown to /bin/sh through standard input as

```
cat a.sh | /bin/sh -s
```

then the question is skipped.

How can I ask the question?

Comment: Is there a reason you are running it this way instead of `/bin/sh a.sh`? The problem is that `a.sh` inherits its standard input from the call to `/bin/sh`, whose standard input is `a.sh`. `/bin/sh` reads the first and second lines, but your `read` statement reads the third line. Since there is no more input for `/bin/sh` to read, it exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `/bin/sh` is reading the script, and your script is reading input, from the same input file: the pipe fed by `cat a.sh`.

One solution is to modify your script to read *directly* from the terminal, not standard input, although that may not be exactly what you want.

```
echo "your age?"
read age < /dev/tty
echo "Your age $age"
```

The better solution is to not read the script from standard input; just pass it as an argument to `/bin/sh`.

```
/bin/sh a.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Try -n option

```
echo -n "your age?"
read age
echo "Your age $age"
```